# Parallel lines with points

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 2 parallel lines.

One of them has 5 points on itself, and the other one has 4 points on itself.

How many triangles are there whose vertices are those points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must these triangles have non-zero area?

Comment: There is no restriction from the point of view.

Comment: If the area can be $0$, where does the fact that the two lines are parallel come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If area does not matter, we can pick any $3$ points out of $4+5$ to form a triangle and end up with
$$
\binom{4+5}{3} = 84
$$
different triangles.

If we want triangles with non-zero area, my attempt would be to pick one point from one of the lines and the two others from the other line:
$$
5 \binom{4}{2} + 4 \binom{5}{2} = 5 \cdot 6 + 4 \cdot 10 = 70
$$

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked about area. A triangle with $3$ points picked from a line has area $0$ and is not considered a feasible triangle here.